# Does not work image optimization on an external website for @nuxt/image

Tags: image, vue.js, optimization, nuxt.js, webp

Can't optimize images on the fly from a remote website.
Example:

```
<nuxt-img
  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/b/b7/Enterthematrix.jpg"
  format="webp"
/>

// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  image: {
    domains: ['https://upload.wikimedia.org']
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working? Did you checked the cache and the size in the network?

Comment: I cleared all of the caches.
Has url like a /_ipx/f_webp/https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/b/b7/Enterthematrix.jpg
Pic is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, when I review the document and finally found out.

Your domain is not valid: you don't need to include the `http` protocol so you should write like this (without http protocol)

```js
export default {
  image: {
    domains: ['upload.wikimedia.org']
  }
}
```